# Iterate over two error messages with same class name and check for one

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, nightwatch.js

I have a page where we have two error messages with same class name. I want to iterate over the class and check for the message that I am looking for and exit the loop in Nightwatch. I was giving it a try, although I know the code is wrong but still posting it.

```
browser.element('css selector', '@SelectionError', function(check) {
    for (var i = 1; i < check.value.length; i++) {
        browser.expect.element('SelectionError').text.to.contain(rejection.errorMessage);
        //browser.assert.containsText('@paymentSelectionError',rejection.errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: Format the code with code formatting and not quote formatting. That can be done with the `{}` button on the question editor, or by using `ctrl+k` on it

Comment: @Isac Formatted the code.